# How to clear Original Values of a detached DevForce entity

Tags: c#, devforce

We are running into various `StackOverflowException` and `OutOfMemoryException`s when sending certain entities to the server as part of an `InvokeServerMethod` call.  The problem seems to come up because DevForce ends up trying to serialize a ton more data than we are expecting it to.  I tracked it down to data that is stored in the `OriginalValuesMap`.

The original values are for `DataEntityProperties` that we've added to the entity but that aren't marked with `[DataMember]` so they normally don't get sent to the server.  *But* if we have an existing (previously saved entity) and then change one of those properties, the initial value of the property *does* end up getting serialized as part of the `OriginalValuesMap`.  This is causing us big problems because it turns out the original value is an entity that has a huge entity graph.

Adding to the problem, the entities we are dealing with are actually clones (via `((ICloneable)origEntity).Clone()`) of existing (previously saved) entities so they have a state of detached and I haven't found a way to clear the `OriginalValuesMap` for detached entities.  Usually I'd do `myEntity.EntityAspect.AcceptChanges()` but that doesn't do anything for detached entities.  I couldn't find any other easy way to do this.

So far, the only way I've found to clear the original values is to attach the entity to an Entity Manager.  This ends up clearing the original values but it is a major pain because I'm actually dealing with a large number of entities (so performance is a concern) and many of these entities don't have unique primary key values (in fact, they don't have any key values filled in because they are just 'in memory' objects that I don't plan to actually ever save) so I need to do extra work to avoid 'duplicate key exception' errors when adding them to an entity manager.

Is there some other way I can clear the original values for a detached entity?  Or should detached entities even be tracking original values in the first place if things like AcceptChanges don't even work for detached entities?  Or maybe a cloned entity shouldn't 'inherit' the original values of its source?  I don't really have a strong opinion on either of these possibilities...I just want to be able to serialize my entities.

Our app is a Silverlight client running DevForce 2012 v7.2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Before diving into the correct behavior for detached entities, I'd like to back up and verify that it really is the OriginalValuesMap which is causing the exception.  The contents of the OriginalValuesMap should follow the usual rules for the DataContractSerializer, so I'd think that non-DataMember items would not be serialized.  Can you try serializing one of these problem entities to a text file to send to IdeaBlade support?  You can use SerializationFns.Save(entity, filename, null, false) to quickly serialize an item.  If it does look like the OriginalValuesMap contains things it shouldn't, I'll also need the type definition(s) involved.

Comment: I can send you a serialized request.  One thing to note, something weird is going on with it because when I tried to deserialize it, I ended up with a multi-gigabyte file and that's after I killed the deserialization process after a while - so there seems to be some kind of infinite loop or something going on there.  But the beginning of the giant file does show the huge value in the OriginalValuesMap.  I'll email it now.